# How to disable RecyclerView Items from clicking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I am using Floating Action Button. I want to disable Recyclerview Items from Clicking when i press FAB button. I tried this method but not working `setClickable(true);`

**My Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.hartwintech.socialchat.activity.IconTabsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/floatmenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        fab:fab_showAnimation="@anim/show_from_bottom"
        fab:fab_hideAnimation="@anim/hide_to_bottom"
        fab:menu_labels_style="@style/MenuLabelsStyle"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#444"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#FFB805"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#F2AB00"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#D99200"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Class**

```
floatMenu.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                if (opened) {
                    final int color = R.color.transp;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        mrecyclerview.setClickable(false);
                        mrecyclerview.setEnabled(false);
                        mrecyclerview.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), color)));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        mrecyclerview.setClickable(true);
                        mrecyclerview.setEnabled(true);
                        mrecyclerview.setForeground(null);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you want to disable or enable?  `setClickable(true);` will make it clickable

Comment: i want to disable

Comment: try `mrecyclerview.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: Tried bro. It's not disabling

Comment: can you post your layout

Comment: posted answer check ...

Comment: Beside the mrecyclerview.setEnabled(false); you'll need to check in the adapter's lister's OnClick event if (mrecyclerview.isEnabled() == false) return;

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add a simple boolean to your adapter like this:

```
public boolean isClickable = true;
```

and set it in your fab-click:

```
mAdapter.isClickable = true/false;
```

And within your OnClickListener in the Adapter, only act when it is clickable:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(!isClickable)
        return;
    // do your click stuff
}
```

Answer (score 27):

To disable RecyclerView, follow below steps:

1. Add following view into your layout file,

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewDisableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#40000000"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

2. Set View Visibility `View.VISIBLE when you want to disable RecyclerView else

Comment: Well played @Rajan, you did the best dirty stuff ever but it worked.

Comment: Nice! I tried this on my own but was missing the 
```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```
part! Thanks genius! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The `RecyclerView` items are still receiving the click events.

Comment: User still could reach RecyclerView items moving focus so its not 100% solution

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use recursion to disable/enable clicks on view

```
 public static void setClickable(View view, boolean clickable) {
        if (view != null) {
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
                for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    setClickable(viewGroup.getChildAt(i), clickable);
                }
            }
            view.setClickable(clickable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Björn Kechel's answer helps me. As he said I just added Boolean. When i click the fab menu the boolean is activated. Then have to write the condition on `mrecyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener`
**Java Class**

```
    public Boolean fabClick = false;

    floatMenu.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
                    if (opened) {
                        final int color = R.color.transp;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            fabClick = true;
                            mrecyclerview.setClickable(false);
                            mrecyclerview.setEnabled(false);
                            mrecyclerview.setForeground(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), color)));
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {                               
                            fabClick = false;
                            mrecyclerview.setClickable(true);
                            mrecyclerview.setEnabled(true);
                            mrecyclerview.setForeground(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

```
            mrecyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), mrecyclerview, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                if(!fabClick) {
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_anim_start, R.anim.fragment_anim_stop);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Group_Chat_Screen.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the click listener to every `FloatingActionButton`.

#### see this issue on **[library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/issues/31)**

Comment: The issue shows related to FloatingActionButton. But i want to disable clicking recyclerview on FloatingActionMenu click

Comment: then you can place view over `RecyclerVIew` make it on gone and don't forget to add `setClickable="true"` on that overlapping view

Comment: I have posted the answer bro. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution with RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@BindingAdapter("itemsClickable")
fun setRecyclerViewClickable(view: RecyclerView, clickable: Boolean) {
    view.isEnabled = clickable
    if (!clickable) {
        val itemTouchListener = object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
            override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView?, e: MotionEvent?) {

            }

            override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView?, e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                return rv?.isEnabled == false
            }

            override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {

            }

        }
        view.addOnItemTouchListener(itemTouchListener)
        view.tag = itemTouchListener
    } else {
        (view.tag as? RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener)?.let {
            view.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
            view.removeOnItemTouchListener(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java

`recyclerView.setOnTouchListener((view1, motionEvent) -> true );`

Kotlin

`reyclerView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }`

this solution disables all touch events

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the touch of recyclerview

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the xml file, set the layout_width and layout_height for **FloatingActionMenu** as match_parent and set clickable as false :

   ```
       android:layout_width="match_parent "
       android:layout_height="match_parent "
       android:clickable="false"
   ```
2. In your java class,

   ```
   floatMenu.setOnMenuToggleListener(new FloatingActionMenu.OnMenuToggleListener() {
           @Override
           public void onMenuToggle(boolean opened) {
               if (opened) {
                  floatMenu.setClickable(true);
               } else {
                    floatMenu.setClickable(false);
               }
           }
       });
   ```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with very simple logic. This will prevent double click on single item and multiple items of `RecyclerView` as well.

Declare a Variable in your Activity.

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
```

Then use in any `OnClickListener`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000){//You can reclick after 1 second
        return;//Before 1 seconds from first click this onclick will return from here
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    
    //Do stuff here

}
```

Actually I found this solution in stackover flow when I was searching for preventing double click on Button. I'm writing this line to acknowledge that actual answer is posted by someone ( Unfortunatly I'm unable to find that answer to link his/her answer here.)

Hope this will solve your problem.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourRecycelerview.suppresslayout(true)
```

Clean, simple and works without item touch listeners or viewholder logic.

Docs:

```
/**
 * Tells this RecyclerView to suppress all layout and scroll calls until layout
 * suppression is disabled with a later call to suppressLayout(false).
 * When layout suppression is disabled, a requestLayout() call is sent
 * if requestLayout() was attempted while layout was being suppressed.
 * <p>
 * In addition to the layout suppression {@link #smoothScrollBy(int, int)},
 * {@link #scrollBy(int, int)}, {@link #scrollToPosition(int)} and
 * {@link #smoothScrollToPosition(int)} are dropped; TouchEvents and GenericMotionEvents are
 * dropped; {@link LayoutManager#onFocusSearchFailed(View, int, Recycler, State)} will not be
 * called.
 *
 * <p>
 * <code>suppressLayout(true)</code> does not prevent app from directly calling {@link
 * LayoutManager#scrollToPosition(int)}, {@link LayoutManager#smoothScrollToPosition(
 *RecyclerView, State, int)}.
 * <p>
 * {@link #setAdapter(Adapter)} and {@link #swapAdapter(Adapter, boolean)} will automatically
 * stop suppressing.
 * <p>
 * Note: Running ItemAnimator is not stopped automatically,  it's caller's
 * responsibility to call ItemAnimator.end().
 *
 * @param suppress true to suppress layout and scroll, false to re-enable.
 */
```