# Disable click/touch for some of a RecyclerView's items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to prevent clicking in a specific item of a recycler view? Already tried to set the view as not clickable and not enabled in the view holder constructor but still with no luck. When I touch an edit text inside that item's layout it is still clickable and will open the keyboard.

Thanks very much in advance!

Edit: This is not the same problem as the one presented in the referenced topic. I do not wish to disable the whole recycle view. Just disable some items from the recycler view. I have already tried the solutions present in the referenced topic to the specific item view and it did not work.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing exactly what you want to do, which probably requires you to add code and images to your post. You say "prevent clicking" but then talk about _focus_ in an EditText.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable RecyclerView Items from clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829485/how-to-disable-recyclerview-items-from-clicking)

Comment: I want to disable clicking in the whole layout of the recycler view item, that includes the views inside the layout (buttons, edittexts etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to completely block interaction with anything inside a single item is to put a transparent view over it that intercepts all touch events. You'd do this by wrapping your existing `itemView` layout in a `FrameLayout` and adding another view on top of that:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- your itemView content here -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Inside `onCreateViewHolder()`, you can assign a no-op click listener to the overlay:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    holder.overlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {});

    return holder;
}
```

Now, when you want to disable clicks, you can call

```
holder.overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and when you want to disable them, you can call

```
holder.overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ben P! I missed the FrameLayout so that the view really overlays the item layout

Comment: P when I call setVisibility(GONE) the view blinks like it is going to disappear and then becomes visible again. Any thoughts? I'm calling setVisibility on the bindType() method after I notifyItemChanged().