# View on top of another using Android's FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I'm trying to place a view on top of another with frame layout. For a view with fixed size it is okay.  The issue is that if the view has a list I can't define the overlay view height. If I set the overlay height as "wrap content" it will take all the screen:

[image]

If i set the height in the xml it will not cover the whole view when views are added to the radioButtonAnswersLinearLayout:

Code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constraining the overlay view to the parent's top, bottom, start and end, so it will expand the overlay to cover the entire view. Remove the bottom constraint and set the height, should work then.

Edit: Re-read the question. If you want to use `wrap_content`, just remove the bottom constraint to parent from the overlay view, and set the height to `wrap_content.`

Edit 2: Change your overlay to a FrameLayout, instead of a view, and set the height to `match_parent`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    ...
    />
```

Comment: Already done with no luck. Removed the bottom constraint from the overlay view and set the height to wrap content and I get the result shown in the screenshot

Comment: Just noticed, the `overlay` view isn't a direct child of a constraint layout, so the constraints are ignored. What are you trying to achieve with this view?

Comment: Ben P. answer to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784292/disable-click-touch-for-some-of-a-recyclerviews-items/52786556#52786556

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you very much! Edit 2 is exactly what I needed