# Prevent RecyclerView from swallowing touch events without creating custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I'm currently working on a UI that looks like this
[image]
The blue part is a ConstraintLayout while the purple part is a RecyclerView inside it (it's a RecyclerView because it's content are dynamic based on service response).

I'm setting `onClick` handler on the ConstraintLayout that would take the user to another page. The problem is the RecyclerView is consuming the clicks and not forwarding it to its parent. Thus `onClick` handler works for the blue area, but not for the purple area.

I tried setting `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` in the RecyclerView but it still won't propagate the clicks to its parent.

One solution I came across is to extend from ConstraintLayout and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` to return true. However I have a strict requirement in my project to not create custom widgets, so I cannot use this solution.

Is there a way to tell RecyclerView to stop consuming touch events?

Activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="#42d7f4"
        android:onClick="navigate"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FRUITS"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/itemsList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#9f41f2"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Item layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Activity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rcView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.itemsList)
        rcView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val items = listOf("Apple", "Banana", "Oranges", "Avocado")
        rcView.adapter = ItemAdapter(items)
    }

    fun navigate(view: View) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Navigating to details page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
}

class ItemAdapter(private val data: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return ItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data[position])
    }
}

class ItemViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val itemTv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.itemText)

    fun bind(item: String) {
        itemTv.text = item
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just make the `RecyclerView` clickable itself? In other words, a click handler is set up for the `ConstraintLayout` and the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Tried to set it on RecyclerView, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You want to scroll `recyclerview` or not? @Abhishek

Comment: @Abhishek you want to scroll of recyclerview but don't want to click?

Comment: @Tanveer actually in this case, I don't even need to scroll the RecyclerView. It's there because of the dynamic nature of the data, but I don't need it's scrolling or recycling features.

Comment: So you can use the overlay on `recyclerview`

Comment: @Abhishek I put my answer please have to look at this

Comment: If the `RecyclerView` doesn't need to scroll, I would go with the overlay as @TanveerMunir suggests or you can use [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) in the activity.

Answer (score 2):

If you freeze the layout after you've set the adapter it no longer swallows clicks:

```
recyclerView.isLayoutFrozen = true // kotlin
recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true); // java
```

Just keep in mind if you need to change the data in the adapter you have to unfreeze the layout before you call notifyDataSetChanged and then re-freeze the layout. I don't love this solution but it's the only one that worked for me.

Comment: Same problem here, this answer works for me I just replaced "setLayoutFrozen(true)" with "suppressLayout(true)" since the first one is deprecated. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to set the `RecyclerView` row with a click listener and to disable clicks and long clicks on the children of the `RecyclerView` row as follows:

```
ConstraintLayout: `android:onClick="navigate"`
   For the item layout: `android:onClick="navigate"`
       TextView: android:clickable="false"
                 android:longClickable="false"
        (etc. for all children of the row)
```

I think what is missing is to make the `TextView` not long clickable.

Answer (score -1):

You can set your `RecyclerView` focus to false.

```
recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
```

And/Or set its rows `view.setFocusable(false);`

**EDIT**

If you want to give the `ConstraintLayout` the focus

```
layout.setFocusable(true);
layout.setClickable(true);

//
// add click listener and event ....
//
```

For more information please refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView?authuser=1) provided by Google

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: I tried setting focusable and clickable to false (both in xml and fragment). The ConstraintLayout still does not get the click event.

Comment: then have you give ConstraintLayout the focus ?

Comment: ConstraintLayout is getting focus in all parts except the RecyclerView. I added code sample to my post.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the easiest way to completely block interaction with anything inside a single view is to put a transparent view over it that intercepts all touch events. You can set click on that view manage all the functionality through that view.

**For example like this**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#42d7f4"

            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/headerText"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FRUITS"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/itemsList"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#9f41f2"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/clickView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:onClick="navigate"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:clickable="true"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Now you can functionality perform through that view instead through `ConstraintLayout`.
Moreover, you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784292/disable-click-touch-for-some-of-a-recyclerviews-items)