# How to disable onTouch of other items in Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is it posible block on touch of other items in Recyclerview by a condition?

For example, when the user click in a item, make other items not clickable, until the condition its true.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/41829794/13373575

Comment: This work for me, one part at least, but when the user click in the disable itens, i want make a toast, and if the clickable is false, i cant do this.

Comment: You can add the Toast before the return. So if clickable = false it will show the Toast and then return.